# Apache Ranger multiple policy repo for Hive Plugin

Tags: apache, security, hive

I recently started working with Apache Ranger on HDP 2.2.6 and was trying to implement 2 active policy repos(Repo1 and Repo2) for the Ranger Hive Plugin. But I found that the policies from only Repo1 were being executed and all the policies from Repo2 were not (even if all the policies in repo1 were disabled).

Do I need to change some config property in Ranger to activate 2 or more repos at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hive Plugin can work with only a single repo at a time.  `ranger.plugin.hive.service.name` property in `ranger-hive-security.xml` (located under hive/hiveserver2 conf directory) corresponds to the repo/service name that plugin uses to fetch policies from ranger admin.

What is the use case that you are trying to address?  Perhaps there is something in existing plugin/policy design that can help you achieve that with single service/repo.

Comment: Thanks Alok, I figured that we can use only one repo at a time and found a work around applicable to my use case. I originally wanted to assign different permissions to various groups with a few people in common but then I had to resort to assigning special permissions to the individual users common to both groups.